# Non-contiguous time series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to create a zoomable time series chart of the number of Tweets that an an account posted per day. My server returns data for the dates where Tweets occurred, that looks like this:

> [
>
> ```
> "2009-01-12",
> 3
> ```
>
> ], [
>
> ```
> "2009-01-15",
> 1
> ```
>
> ], [
>
> ```
> "2009-01-16",
> 1
> ```
>
> ], [
>
> ```
> "2009-01-30",
> 2
> ```
>
> ]

I know that the ISO 8601 date can be converted with `Date.parsedate()`. Can I register it as a callback to convert the dates? How can I create a zoomable chart with irrigular intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to loop through your array and parse that date to get timestamp, for example:

```
var parsedDate = [];
for(var i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++){
    var t = your_array[i],
        d = (new Date(t[0])).getTime();
    parsedData.push([d, t[1]]);
}
```

And then assign to series data in options:

```
series: [{
    data: parsedData;
}]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing .getTime(). I reduced your code to `data['dates'].map(function(d) {d[0]=new Date(d[0]).getTime(); return d;})`